# Symfony2 seems to break __autoload

Tags: php, symfony, autoload

I'm currently integrating non symfony2 software (let's call it *nsf*) in an sf2 project. That software uses `__autoload`.

When trying to access some *nsf* features in a twig extension, I get fatal errors about classes not found. It appears that when called from symfony2 code, the `__autoload` function is not called at all.

I recently moved to php5 so this might sound like a newbie question but I'm trying to figure out what's going on.

Thanks for your clues.

Comment: This might not be directly tied with symfony2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a problem originating in the usage of `__autoload`. If you can, replace those calls with the 'new' `spl_autoload_register()` call currently adviced:

see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

> spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

`__autoload()` is only one function, and is prone to overriding if 2 files want to do something with that. Using `spl_autoload_register()` means you can register several autoload functions.